# Создание buttons в tableLayout

Tags: android

Для игры "Крестики-нолики" использую tableLayout, крашу в черный, добавляю 3 строки и 3 столбца, и в ячейки помещаю Button. Используя равный вес получаю равномерные ячейки. Когда выставляю margin для button-а то получается сетка. В общем вот так вот сделал поле. Сначала в xml разметке. Все прекрасно выглядит.

[image: Поле для игры "Крестики-нолики" в xml разметке]

Вот разметка:
**fragment_game.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewLogoF2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="40dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="40dp"
        android:text="TicTacToe"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        android:textSize="80sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="50dp"
        android:paddingRight="50dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1F2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:text="Игрок 1"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_light"
            android:textSize="36sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2F2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:text="Игрок 2"
            android:textAlignment="textEnd"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_light"
            android:textSize="36sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableGame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="50dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button10"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/white" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/white" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/white" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button9"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/white" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/white" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/white" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button8"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/white" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/white" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/white" />
        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Дальше необходимо сделать это все в коде, для того чтобы была возможность создавать поля разных размеров.
Поэтому в приведенной выше разметке я удалил теги TableRow, таким образом остался пустой TableLayout.
Дальше в java файле прописал такой код:
Часть кода **FragmentGame.java**, ( **mRange = 3** )

```
Log.d("MyLogs", "Нахожу Layout");
TableLayout tabLay = (TableLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.tableGame);
for(int i = 0; i < mRange; i++){
    Log.d("MyLogs", "Создаю строку");
    TableRow tr = new TableRow(getActivity());

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams RowParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1);
    tr.setLayoutParams(RowParams);

    for(int j = 0; j < mRange; j++){
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1);
        params.setMargins(2, 2, 2, 2);
        Log.d("MyLogs", "Создаю кнопку");
        Button btn = new Button(getActivity());
        btn.setLayoutParams(params);
        btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

        tr.addView(btn, j);
    }
    tabLay.addView(tr, i);
}
```

Но при запуске ячейки не создаются. Помогите пожалуйста правильно создать это поле.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы используете неверный класс для лэйаут параметров. Тип параметров должен быть такой, как тип родительской вью, в которой вы добавляете элемент. То есть, раз кнопки вы добавляете в `TableRow`, то тип параметров должен быть:

```
TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(
        TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
        1);
Button btn = new Button(getActivity());
btn.setLayoutParams(params);
```

`TableRow` добавляется в `TableLayout`, соответственно:

```
TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
TableLayout.LayoutParams rowParams = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
        TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
        TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
        1);
tr.setLayoutParams(rowParams);
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте в java тоже ширину кнопки дать как `wrap_content` так-как Вы в Xml дали кнопкам ширину как `wrap_content` а в Java как `match_parent`.

И второе когда Ваш внутренний цикл повторяется он кнопкам начинает давать тот же ID `tr.addView(btn, j);`. Значение `j` 0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2.